# What in the world is wrong with me?

Tags: riddle

I have a riddle that seems to be quite tricky... here it is:

> Wrong always I shall be 
>   Correct everyone shall see me as 
>   But to be wrong is to be right

What am I?

Comment: I guess not one of the literal possibilities, such as: a perfect timepiece correct to within one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time

Answer (score 6):

> The word 'Wrong'
>
>    'Wrong' will always be 'wrong' and spelt correctly it is right.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> a car's indicator light on a reversing car?

Wrong always I shall be

> If the right-indicator is on, the car will actually be turning left in it's direction of motion

Correct everyone shall see me as

> Everyone knows the car is reversing as the car is in motion

But to be wrong is to be right

> Putting on the other indicator light would be incorrect

Comment: Not the right answer but a good one!

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

> A Lie

Wrong always it is, Correct everyone shall see it as,
To be it is to be right by choice.

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> Strikeout text (e.g. <s>wrong</s>)
>  - You indicate that something is wrong but make the result right and it's viewed as corrected.

Or maybe:

> A reflection in a mirror
>  - The image is laterally inverted and hence wrong in a way.  But when you look at the mirror, it looks correct; and in fact if it were not flipped it would look wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> An eye's retina (or the light shining on it)

because

> light gets flipped the "wrong" way by the lens, but you *see* it the "right" way around.

Comment: Nice but incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> Left Handed

Wrong always I shall be

> You are not **right** handed

Correct everyone shall see me as

> Your left handedness appear to the right side of people seeing you.

But to be wrong is to be right

> For you being **right** handed seems wrong

Answer (score 1):

You may be

> The lettering on the front of an emergency vehicle like an ambulance. 
>  Wrong always I shall be  - the type is a mirror image.
>  Correct everyone shall see me as - it is seen correctly through a rear view mirror.
>  But to be wrong is to be right - it is more easily read to the most relevant persons this way.